# How to print _matchingData object value in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have printed object and trying to print Tenats.stage

```
<?php foreach ($tenancies as $tenancy): ?>

    <td><?= debug($tenancy); ?></td>
```

Print this =>

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Tenancy) {

    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

        'time' => '2016-03-18T15:57:40+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'tenants' => [],
    'property' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

        'id' => (int) 4110,
        'address1' => '119 Alan Moss Road',
        'postcode' => 'le115ly',
        '[new]' => false,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Properties'

    },
    '_matchingData' => [
        'Tenants' => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'stage' => (int) 2,
            '[new]' => false,
            '[accessible]' => [
                '*' => true
            ],
            '[dirty]' => [],
            '[original]' => [],
            '[virtual]' => [],
            '[errors]' => [],
            '[invalid]' => [],
            '[repository]' => 'Tenants'

        }
    ],
```

I need to 'stage' value

Any help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how to print _matchingData

```
<td><?= h($tenancy->_matchingData['Tenants']->stage); ?></td>
```

But if you specify the main parents field id (Tenancy.id) automaticaly your data will look much much better. for example my parent model is "Tenancy" Now I am getting Tenant.id and Tenancy.id and Property.id :

```
$tenancies = $this
            ->find()
            ->select([ 
                'Tenancy.id', 'Tenancy.created', 'Tenancy.stage',
                'Properties.id', 'Properties.address1', 'Properties.postcode',
                'Tenants.stage',
            ])
            ->contain('Properties', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                return $query->where([
                    'Properties.active' => 1
                ]);
            })
            ->contain([
                'Tenants'  
            ])
            ->matching('Tenants', function(\Cake\ORM\Query $query) {
                return $query->where([
                    'Tenants.active' => 1
                ]);
            })
            ->where([
                'Tenancy.active' => 1,
                $conditions
            ])
            ->order([
                'Tenancy.created' => 'DESC',
                'Tenants.tenancy_id'
            ]); 

        return $tenancies;
    }
```

It prints the array with deep associations which is cool and I can get my tenants property like this:

```
 <td><?= h($tenancy->tenants->stage); ?></td>
```

Prints=>

```
0 => object(App\Model\Entity\Tenancy) {

    'id' => (int) 3923,
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

        'time' => '2016-03-19T13:12:32+00:00',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'stage' => (int) 2,
    'tenants' => [
        (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'id' => (int) 8903,
            'user_id' => (int) 15318,
            'tenancy_id' => (int) 3923,
            'needs_guarantor' => true,
            'guarantor_id' => null,
            'holding_fee' => (float) 50,
```

**Result:** Make sure always you write your query properly so you access your data nice and tidy.