# How to avoid _matchingData and get a specific value instead

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In the Orders Table Model I need the category ids of the products associated with the order

**Model/Table/OrdersTable.php**

```
    public function updateQuantityForInventoryItems(array $orders_items): void
    {
        $ordersItemsIds = [];

        foreach ($orders_items as $orders_item) {
            array_push($ordersItemsIds, $orders_item->product_id);
        }

        $catIds = $this->find('ordersItemsCategories', ['ordersItemsIds' => $ordersItemsIds])->toArray();

        dd($catIds);

        $InventoriesTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Inventories');
        $InventoriesTable->updateQuantityForInventoryItems('orders', $catIds);
    }

    public function findOrdersItemsCategories(Query $query, array $options): Query
    {
        $query = $this->OrdersItems->Products
            ->find()
            ->select(['Products.id','CategoriesProducts.category_id'])
            ->matching(
                'CategoriesProducts', function (Query $q) use ($options) {
                return $q->where([
                    'CategoriesProducts.product_id IN' => $options['ordersItemsIds'],
                ]);
            });

        return $query->hydrate(false);
    }
```

**the generated SQL query**

```
SELECT Products.id AS `Products__id`, CategoriesProducts.category_id AS `CategoriesProducts__category_id` FROM products Products INNER JOIN categories_products CategoriesProducts ON (CategoriesProducts.product_id in (4325,3632) AND Products.id = (CategoriesProducts.product_id))
```

When I print out the array with `dd($catIds);` , I get an array with _matchingData

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3632
    "_matchingData" => array:1 [▼
      "CategoriesProducts" => array:1 [▼
        "category_id" => 10
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => ...
]
```

how do i get category_id under id

(i have already checked that thread [How to print _matchingData object value in cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096262/how-to-print-matchingdata-object-value-in-cakephp-3) but still no success)

Answer (score 0):

got it. i need to alias the category_id to prevent nesting

```
->select(['category_id' => 'CategoriesProducts.category_id'])
```